# In Firebase Analytics, can i create a custom event similar to SELECT_CONTENT event

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

In SELECT_CONTENT (firebase build in event) the params have an hierarchy:
`SELECT_CONTENT` > `CONTENT_TYPE` > `ITEM_ID`
and when you enter SELECT_CONTENT in the "Events" tab in the dashboard you will walk through them in this order - similar to google analytics (category > action > label)

Now, when i create an event like this:
`MY_EVENT_NAME` > `MY_FIRST_PARAM` > `MY_SECOND_PARAM`
and then enter the event in the dashboard, i just see the 2 params' "sections" with their count but they are not clickable so it's like one is not related to the other, which make sense cause i haven't done anything that tell their hierarchy to Firebase.

So, my question is: 
Is there a way to make it work like SELECT_CONTENT and other built in events?
(If not, this is really disappointing ): )

Comment: Did you find the solution yet? This really is very painful!

Comment: Sadly i did not..